# Working with Command Prompt in Python using Subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess

In my script, I need to bring up the command prompt which I have not had any issues in creating:

```
subprocess.Popen([r"cmd.exe"])
```

That is essentially what I have done so far. I have some arguments that want to be placed in this prompt, that I want automatically ran when I run the script.

What I would like to do is change my directory in the prompt using only Python. Would anybody have any idea how to get there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) takes a keyword argument to specify the current working directory. Simply do this:

```
subprocess.Popen(r"cmd.exe", cwd = "my/lovely/directory/", "more-args")
```

Comment: That seems to have worked! Thanks! If I wanted to include an argument, like running a .bat file, where would I include this? This .bat file would be inside the current working directory.

Comment: I don't normally use subprocess, but I know that it has everything that you can imagine. Check out the docs, it will really help you out. It's bigger than the world encyclopedia... Also, if it worked, you could mark as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I have no idea about subprocess, but you could use the os module to change directories, start command prompt, run a batch program, etc.

```
import os
os.chdir('blah')
os.system('start something.bat')
```

Depends on if you strictly need to use subprocess. Hope that helps though!